# Tag display wraps across lines

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

The list of tags at the bottom of a question is wrapping after the left border of a tag (view [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/440338/why-does-performance-of-a-regular-hard-drive-decrease-over-the-duration-of-a-ben/) in Opera(perhaps other browsers also) and look at bottom tag list.
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot, showing bad tag wraparound]

Comment: Tags have *always* looked messed up in some way in one browser or another... it's time they get fixed...

Comment: Could we use some form of image generation(akin to PHP's gd library) to actually create an image to represent the tag as a workaround? I know browser support is spotty.

Comment: Fellow **Opera** user, we must deal with it

Comment: The devs must use Firefox. I've only experienced CSS issues with other browsers.

Comment: BTW I can't reproduce this in Chromium on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't repro in Opera 18 or 19 (it has probably been fixed)

[image]

Comment: Your viewport resolution may potentially affect it, though this is fairly old now.

Comment: @hexafraction I tried changing it.

Comment: OK, it probably is just too old and got fixed (in Opera or SE).

Comment: As a daily Opera 12.16 user I can assure that SE has fixed this some time ago. It has nothing to do with the new Opera 15+ engine "Bling"